# Is a topology a Ring with unions being comparable to "addition" and intersections being comparable to "multiplication"?

Tags: general-topology

I'm taking a topology class and I've previously taken a class on groups and rings. I'm curious if a topology is just a ring and if any fancy math involves this?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "comparable".  It won't be a ring in the usual algebraic sense as there is no inverse to the addition.

Answer (score 1):

No, a topology is not a ring in the algebraic sense of the term. In a ring, every element has an additive inverse. Neither the union operation, nor the intersection operation has inverse elements. To turn the power set of a set into a ring, you need to use the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) instead of the union. With symmetric difference as addition and intersection as multiplication, the power set of a set has the structure of a [Boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring). The additive identity is $\emptyset$, the additive inverse of $S$ is $S$, and the multiplicative identity is the entire set.

But this construction doesn’t apply to topologies in general. (The power set is a specific example of a topology, the [discrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space).) That’s because the symmetric difference can’t be defined in terms of unions and intersections alone; it requires taking complements, and a topology need not be closed under taking complements.

A more subtle point is that a topology isn’t just closed under finite unions and intersections but also under arbitrary unions, which have no analogue in a ring.

Comment: A topology (or more generally, a distributive lattice) is a semiring (ring without additive inverses), however.